How to calculate and know I got the complete eigensystem of $L_K$ under $K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) := (\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{y})^2$?
I am currently researching some stuff on RKHS and Mercer's theorem, and I fear I might have forgot some fundamental stuff since I can't figure out how the following works out: Let $K: \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a Mercer kernel defined by
$$K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) := (\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{y})^2$$
and define the integral operator $L_K: L_2(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow L_2(\mathbb{C})$ by
$$(L_K f)(x) := \int_{\mathbb{C}^2} K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) f(\mathbf{y}) \, d\mathbf{y}$$
This is exactly the integral operator that we use the eigensystem of in Mercer's theorem. Intuitively, $K$ can be decomposed
$$K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \overline{x_1}^2 y_1^2 + 2\overline{x_1x_2}y_1y_2+\overline{x_2}^2y_2^2 = \phi_1(\mathbf{x})\overline{\phi_1(\mathbf{y})} + 2\phi_2(\mathbf{x})\overline{\phi_2(\mathbf{y})} + \phi_3(\mathbf{x})\overline{\phi_3(\mathbf{y})}$$
for appropriately defined functions,  e.g. $\phi_1(\mathbf{y}) := \overline{y_1}^2$. According to Mercer's theorem, these should correspond to the eigenfunctions of $L_K$ since the $\phi_i$ can be shown to be an ONB for $\mathcal{H} = \overline{\text{span}\{K(\cdot,\mathbf{x}): \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^2\}}$ (the RKHS associated with $K$). But... how do I actually know that I got all the eigefunctions by just rewriting $K$ like that?
Alas, to verify that the functions defined above are indeed eigenvectors, let's calculate e.g.
$$\begin{align}
(L_K \phi_1)(\mathbf{x}) &= \int_{\mathbb{C}^2} K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) \phi_1(\mathbf{y}) \, d\mathbf{y}
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{C}^2} \overline{x_1}^2 |y_1|^4 + 2\overline{x_1x_2}|y_1|^2\overline{y_1}y_2+\overline{x_2}^2\overline{y_1}^2y_2^2 \, d\mathbf{y}
\\
&= \text{ ???}
\\
&= \overline{x_1}^2
\\
&= \phi_1(\mathbf{x})
\end{align}$$
To summarize, my questions are as follows:


How does one go from the (what feels like unbounbed) integral over $\mathbb{C}^2$ to the expression for the eigenfunction?
How do I actually show that $\phi_1$ to $\phi_3$ span the entirety of $\mathcal{H}$, i.e. why does the "Kernel rewriting trick" work?


Once this calculation makes sense, it should not be too hard to extrapolate to vectors of arbitrary size and some other kernels, so any help is appreciated!
